# AngularJS:Error , Array value existing even after set to null?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-digest

```
    function detailCtrl($scope, $state, $stateParams, documentService, $q) {
            var self = this;
            self.detailedDocObj = null;
            init();
            function init() {
                self.docId = $stateParams.documentId;
                getFiledetails();
            }
            function getFiledetails() {
                documentService.getDetailedDocument(self.docId, getDocumentSuccess, failure);
            }

          function getDocumentSuccess(detailedDocObj) {
               if (detailedDocObj) {
                 self.detailedDocObj = detailedDocObj;

             }
         }

    }
```

I have a controller in which I am loading some data by calling service, and on its success call back I am using those data to render it on UI.

Below is the code for service

```
function getDetailedDocument(docId, callback, errback) {
            var url = "Document/Get?fileId=" + docId;
            httpWrapperService.get(url).then(
                function success(data) {
                    callback(srvToJsDoc(data));
                },
                function error(errorObject) {
                    errback(error);
                }
            );
        }




function srvToJsDoc(srvDoc) {
            if (srvDoc) {
                var jsDoc = {
                    creationDate: srvDoc.CreationDate
                }
                //Problem in array
                var documentVersions = [];
                for (var index in srvDoc.DocumentVersions) {
                    var doc = srvDoc.DocumentVersions[index];
                    documentVersions.push(
                    {
                        id: doc.Id,
                        name: doc.Name,
                        label: doc.Label,
                        userName: doc.Username,
                        creationDate: doc.CreationDate
                    });
                }
                jsDoc.documentVersions = documentVersions;
                return jsDoc;
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Now You can see in srvDoc function I am creating a new array and storing the value from srvDoc.DocumentVersions array.

On success callback Inside my controller I am getting the `object detailedDocObj` correctly. But On my console I get the error

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: function (){return o(a)}","newVal":[],"oldVal":[]}],[{"msg":"fn: function (){return o(a)}","newVal":[],"oldVal":"<<already seen>>"}],[{"msg":"fn: function (){return o(a)}","newVal":[],"oldVal":"<<already seen>>"}],[{"msg":"fn: function (){return o(a)}","newVal":[],"oldVal":"<<already seen>>"}],[{"msg":"fn: function (){return o(a)}","newVal":[],"oldVal":"<<already seen>>"}]]
```

I have gone through some other posts also , but could not able to figure it out, whats and where is the probl;em happening in array.And also I debug the code on page load even though I am setting `null value in  self.detailedDocObj` , but still I am able to see the array value `DocumentVersion` it holds during the service call.

What error I am doing , Not able to find out. 
Any help is appreciated 
Thanks!!!